# Segmentation fault on icpc-compiled program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, icc

I am having problems understanding the segmentation fault I receive when trying to run icpc-compiled programs.

A simple example consists of the following files:

```cpp
// Filename: include/lib1.h
#include <string>

namespace Lib1 {
  // Template initialization, T: int, double
  template< typename T>
    T function1( T x, T y );

  // Give me the version
  std::string VERSION(void);
}
```

```cpp
// Filename: include/lib2.h
#include <string>

namespace Lib2 {
  // Give me the version
  std::string VERSION(void);
}
```

```cpp
// Filename: src/main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "lib1.h"
#include "lib2.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  std::cout << "Lib1::VERSION() :" << Lib1::VERSION()
            << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Lib2::VERSION() :" << Lib2::VERSION()
            << std::endl;

  double x = 1., y = 2.;

  std::cout << "Lib1::function1(x, y): "
            << Lib1::function1(x, y)
            << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// Filename: src/lib1/lib1.cpp
#include <string>

#include "lib1.h"

template< typename T >
T Lib1::function1( T x, T y ) {
  return x * y;
}

std::string Lib1::VERSION(void) {
  return std::string("v0.0.2");
}

// Instantiation for dynamic library
template double Lib1::function1(double, double);
template int Lib1::function1(int, int);
```

```
// Filename: src/lib2/lib2.cpp
#include <string>

#include "lib2.h"

std::string Lib2::VERSION(void) {
  return std::string("v0.0.1");
}
```

In this simple, stupid example, when I compile the files using

```
clang++ -Wall -c -fPIC -I include -o liblib1.o src/lib1/lib1.cpp
clang++ -Wall -shared -o liblib1.so liblib1.o
clang++ -Wall -c -fPIC -I include -o liblib2.o src/lib2/lib2.cpp
clang++ -Wall -shared -o liblib2.so liblib2.o
clang++ -Wall -o main.out -I include -L ./ -llib1 -llib2 src/main.cpp
```

the program runs fine (provided that I modify my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable properly. However, when I use

```
icpc -Wall -c -fPIC -I include -o liblib1.o src/lib1/lib1.cpp
icpc -Wall -shared -o liblib1.so liblib1.o
icpc -Wall -c -fPIC -I include -o liblib2.o src/lib2/lib2.cpp
icpc -Wall -shared -o liblib2.so liblib2.o
icpc -Wall -o main.out -I include -L ./ -llib1 -llib2 src/main.cpp
```

then the program gives me:

```
[1]    27397 segmentation fault (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./main.out
```

I would appreciate if you helped me understand and solve this problem. When I did some research on the web, I came across some sources talking about memory access problems and such, but I am not doing anything fancy right now. Moreover, I tried using `ddd` (I am not fluent/good in `gdb`) and running the program there, but the program exists with the segfault immidiately after the program start. I cannot even trace the program (yes, prior to running `ddd`, I used `-debug -g` switches).

Comment: [FWIW] [templates need to be defined in the header file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: I am sorry @NathanOliver, but I could not understand the problem. In the link provided, the solution is *exactly* the same as what I have done in providing the above examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to be the case that **Intel Parallel Studio v16.0.3** has (known) issues for [Ubuntu](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/637950) and [Arch Linux](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/670092) platforms, and unfortunately these systems are not officially supported, either.

One fast workaround seems to be to downgrade to **v16.0.2** for now.